# Tensorflow & Keras Layer "sequential" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am having an issue when trying to create a model with Keras where if I try to run it, it complains about the sequential layer getting too many inputs. This is the error:

```py
ValueError: Layer "sequential" expects 1 input(s), but it received 2 input tensors.
Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(1, 90, 60, 3) dtype=uint8>,
<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>]
```

My input is several RGB images that are 60x90 pixels (width x height).
Here is my model:

```py
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (90, 60, 3), name="conv_1"))
network.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name="maxpool_1"))
network.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', name="conv_2"))
network.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name = "maxpool_2"))
network.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu', name="conv_3"))
network.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name = "maxpool_3"))
network.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu', name="conv_4"))
network.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2), name = "maxpool_4"))

network.add(layers.Flatten())
network.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = 'relu', name="dense_1"))
network.add(layers.Dense(6, activation = 'sigmoid', name="dense_2"))
```

The goal of this model is to tell the location of something in an image, split into 6 parts of the image, so the _px in the following code represents the pixel data of the images, and the _loc represents the correct answer for the provided image.

```py
training_data_px = dataset_px[:training_images]
test_data_px = dataset_px[training_images:]

training_data_loc = dataset_loc[:training_images]
test_data_loc = dataset_loc[training_images:]

training_data = (numpy.asarray(training_data_px), numpy.asarray(training_data_loc))
test_data = (numpy.asarray(test_data_px), numpy.asarray(test_data_loc))
```

This is the shape of `training_data[0]` and `training_data[1]`:

```py
(30, 90, 60, 3)
(30,)
```

This is the compilation and fit function of the network:

```py
network.compile(optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),
               loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
               metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = network.fit(training_data,
                        steps_per_epoch = 50,
                        epochs=50,
                        validation_data = test_data,
                        validation_steps=50
                        )
```

What does the error mean and how to resolve it?

Comment: the problem is when you call `predict/fit/evaluate`, please post that part of the code

Comment: please try with `network.fit(training_data[0],training_data[1]...)`... what you are doing is completely different, is used when a model has 2 inputs

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Agreed, I think you could reasonably post that as an answer

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia please explain further.. I don't understand

Comment: @Menotdan sure, allow me an hour and i’ll explain it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is how you are passing the parameters to the `fit` method, in particular the correct way in your case would be this:

```py
history = network.fit(
                        training_data[0],
                        training_data[1],
                        steps_per_epoch = 50,
                        epochs=50,
                        validation_data = test_data,
                        validation_steps=50
                        )
```

In other words, the first 2 parameters usually are `x` (input, first one) and `y` (target, second one), but the second one can be omitted if there is no target (see for example siamese NN)